# DataGridView row text disappears on every row except the selected one

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

[image]

Only the selected row's text appears on the DataGridView. I've tried adding the rows via a DataTable and the setting the data source and just adding the rows directly to the gridview.

```
dgvCudaMiner_Failover.Rows.Add(object.property1.ToString(), object.property2, object.property3, object.property4, true, object.property5.ToString());
```

Any ideas on what's going on? I tried changing all the columns to text columns to see if that would work, but it didn't.

Comment: any chance cell's foreground color was set to the same color as background? The text is actually there, but you can't see it until background color changed to blue (which happen when a row selected)

Comment: @har07 Thanks! That was the problem. The DefaultCellStyle property had the ForeColor all messed up for some reason. Submit this as an answer so I an accept it, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer as requested.

> I suspect, cell's foreground color was set to the same color as background. The text is actually there, but you can't see it until background color changed to blue (which happen when a row selected)